# How do I make this JavaScript code portable?

Tags: javascript, http, cross-browser

The following code works only in Chrome. I need it to run on all major browsers. Firefox and IE load the image once. Opera doesn't load it at all.

The screen.jpg file is sent with `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`. I cannot use a library like jQuery because they're too big.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh()
{
    document.getElementById("screen").src = "screen.jpg";
    setTimeout("refresh()", 500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0" onload="refresh()">
<img id="screen" style="width:100%"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery minified is 30kb. Is that really "too big"?

Comment: Maybe not too big in size but too big to understand in 2 minutes

Comment: argh - string parameter to `setTimeout`!  It should just be `setTimeout(refresh, 500)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can append random number to the end of source so that the image is re-requested every time:

```
document.getElementById("screen").src = "screen.jpg?" + Math.random()*999999;
```

Comment: The `Cache-Control` header is supposed to make that unnecessary.

Comment: Yes but if you set the same src all the time, browser will not request file again. It does remain unchanged